# Building android project with ant, using of zlib.so

Tags: android, linux, ant, build, 32bit-64bit

I'm trying to build an android project using ant.
So, when I try to run "ant debug", I get the following error :

```
[aapt] /<path-to-SDK>/build-tools/17.0.0/aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64
```

What I understand here is that aapt need a 32b version of libz.so. (Is this right ?)
I saw some people (working on debian, I'm on openSUSE 12.1) resolving their issue by installing ia32-libs. Where could I find something similar ?

Thanks !

Comment: Is your OS 32-bit or 64-bit? Are you using the right version of the SDK? http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#download

Comment: My OS is 64-bit, the binary android works as it should.
Edit : The SDK download is the same for linux 32b and 64b

Comment: The page offers 2 different versions for me with different filenames. Btw, I'm on 64-bit Debian, using Android Studio, and the `aapt` and `adb` that came with it are 32-bit.

Comment: I downloaded the adt bundle and tried to build a project with it. Got the same error in eclipse console,     aapt needs a 32-bit version of libz.so.